# Replace -1 in pandas series with unique values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas series that can have positive integers (0, 8, 10, etc) and -1s:

```
id      values
1137    -1
1097    -1
201      8
610     -1
594     -1
727     -1
970     21
300     -1
243      0
715     -1
946     -1
548      4
Name: cluster, dtype: int64
```

I want to replace those -1 with values that don't already exist in the series and that are unique between them, in other words, I can't fill twice with, for example, 90. What's the most pythonic way to do that?

Here is the expected output:

```
id      values
1137     1
1097     2
201      8
610      3
594      5
727      6
970     21
300      7
243      0
715      9
946     10
548      4
Name: cluster, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What is your question ? What is your expected output?

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: Any values that I want as long as the result Series is unique?

Comment: Yes! That's it @Adam.Er8

Comment: OK, lemme have a try

Comment: Sorry, it really wasn't quite clear, just edited know, see if it is more understandable

Comment: @Bruno I take it your expected output for id=243 should be 0 and not 8? (the accepted answer seems to confirm that but does make it a bit confusing for someone else reading the Q and seeing the A)

Comment: @JonClements You are right, just edited it, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create all possible values by `np.arange` with add more values for positives, then get difference with positives and set to filtered column:

```
m = df['values'] != -1

s = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(df) + m.sum()), df.loc[m, 'values'])
df.loc[~m, 'values'] = s[:(~m).sum()]
print (df)
      id  values
0   1137       1
1   1097       2
2    201       8
3    610       3
4    594       5
5    727       6
6    970      21
7    300       7
8    243       0
9    715       9
10   946      10
11   548       4
```